# « Éclater un ballon » ou « faire éclater un ballon » ?

Tags: sens, verbes

Comme il y a « le ballon éclate », on dit « faire éclater un ballon » ou plutôt « éclater un ballon » ? Selon [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9clater/27563?q=%C3%A9clater#27417), « éclater » est surtout un verbe intransitif, donc je ne suis pas sûr que la seconde phrase marche, mais je l'ai [vu](https://www.larecherche.fr/deux-fa%C3%A7ons-d%C3%A9clater-un-ballon-de-baudruche) sur internet malgré ça.

Comment: Notons que dans le nord de la France et en Belgique, on utilise aussi parfois le terme "camper" à cette fin, de manière transitive et intransitive : "Le ballon a approché les cactus de trop près et donc il a campé (=éclaté)" ou "Maman, Jules a campé (= fait éclater) mon ballon !". Peut-être est-ce dû à cela que je ne trouve pas l'emploi transitif de "éclater" particulièrement dérangeant, même si incorrect.

Comment: Je suis belge (de Bruxelles) mais je ne pense pas avoir déjà entendu cet usage de "camper"..  Dans quelle région de Belgique la rencontre-t-on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On peut trouver un usage transitif en langage familier, mais utilisé avec un COI (et cela est plutôt utilisé avec des parties du corps).

> Je me suis éclaté l'orteil en trébuchant.
>
> Je vais t'éclater la tronche !

ou au sens imagé de "s'amuser", sous forme pronominale:

> Je me suis éclaté  à cette fête !.

Answer (score 1):

À la façon anglaise, on peut dire « bouillir de l'eau », « bouillir une casserole d'eau » (boil some water, boil a saucepanful of water) au lieu de « faire bouillir de l'eau/une casserole d'eau », mais c'est un usage attesté ([réf.](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bouillir)).   On devrait pouvoir  dire « éclater un ballon », cependant le verbe « éclater » est strictement intransitif.
On emploi déjà cette construction dans d'autres cas où on retrouve la même particularité de syntaxe ; en termes approximatifs c'est la possibilité de transférer l'action en mode intransitif du complément à une même action du sujet mais en mode transitif ou le complément devient le complément d'objet parce que la forme verbale est constructible selon les deux possibilités. Les deux sont correctes.

- monter des œufs en neige : le cuisinier, en réalité, *fait* changer la masse d'albumine en une mousse par un brassage constant et on pourrait dire de façon aussi correcte « faire monter des œufs en neige ».
- rentrer le bétail à l'étable/faire rentrer le bétail à l'étable ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+rentrer+le+b%C3%A9tail&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20rentrer%20le%20b%C3%A9tail%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfaire%20rentrer%20le%20b%C3%A9tail%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bde%20rentrer%20le%20b%C3%A9tail%3B%2Cc0))
- sécher le linge dans le séchoir/faire sécher le linge dans le séchoir ([réf;](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+s%C3%A9cher+le+linge&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20s%C3%A9cher%20le%20linge%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfaire%20s%C3%A9cher%20le%20linge%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%C3%A0%20s%C3%A9cher%20le%20linge%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpour%20s%C3%A9cher%20le%20linge%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfait%20s%C3%A9cher%20le%20linge%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bet%20s%C3%A9cher%20le%20linge%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bde%20s%C3%A9cher%20le%20linge%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfaisait%20s%C3%A9cher%20le%20linge%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfont%20s%C3%A9cher%20le%20linge%3B%2Cc0))
- sonner les cloches/faire sonner les cloches (usage attesté)

Answer (score 1):

"Faire éclater un ballon" est la seule tournure correcte. "Eclater un ballon" est impropre et à vrai-dire peu clair. Quant à "je me suis éclaté", c'est du langage parlé familier, d'ailleurs plutôt mal parlé, ni argot, ni verlan, simplement pauvre.

Comment: pauvre ou simplement familier, selon le point de vue...